# Why flatmap is needed in state monads?

Tags: functional-programming, state-monad

Sorry for the very naive question.

I understand that the essence of state monads is a map of type S => (S,A) in which S is the type for states, A is a type for a computation result. Then the essence of a state monad would be defined as (in Scala)

```
class StateMonad[S,A](transition: S => (S,A))
```

And that should be all, not big deal. Why so many books also put `flatMap` into the definition of a state monad ? What would be the motivation besides the arguments such as "otherwise, playing with states would become error-prone"? As far as I could see, `flatMap` makes sense mostly for Lists, or Collections. So, I really miss some big picture here. Can someone clarify? Thank you.

I wish to see an answer requiring no knowledge about monads. In fact, I am reading the State Monad chapter in a textbook before the monad concept has been actually introduced. The language I start to learn using is Scala.

Comment: `flatMap` is a requirement for all monads.

Comment: @lee yeah that is the problem for my understanding as I am reading the State Monad chapter before the monad concept has been actually introduced.  Can you explain why flatMap is needed for handling states, or the specific state monad?

Comment: Yeah, isn't `flatMap` a requirement? Some places call it `bind` but ultimately it takes a function that returns a monad and transforms the current monad with it. So it's not just the State monad, but any monad needs it. You can't effectively work with monads without it.

Answer (score 2):

The `flatMap` function is what gives rise to the extra power that you get from using a `Monad` as opposed to weaker (and hence more general) structures like `Functor` and `Applicative`. For `State` this function has type:

```
def flatMap[S, A, B](f: A => State[S, B], state: State[S, A]): State[S, B]
```

within the function `f` you can inspect the result of a previous stateful computation and use it to decide how to procede in the rest of the computation e.g.

```
def branch1: State[Int, String]
def branch2: State[Int, String]
def decide(s: State[Int, Int]): State[Int, String] =
    flatMap(x => if x > 5 then branch1 else branch2, s)
```

Comment: @zell - Which bit is unclear? `flatMap` lets you combine `State` values together while choosing between alternatives based on the result of the previous computation.

Comment: I find the correlation between the properties weak and general quite interesting. What exactly do you mean with weak? Is a structure weaker than another when the portion you know about it, i.e. the typeclass it implements, is less specific? This explanation would be still fuzzy, though. What makes a typeclass less specific than another?

Comment: @bob - Yes I mean the typeclass is less specific and hence less powerful. `Applicative` is a subtype of `Functor` and `Monad` is a subtype of `Applicative` and the operations defined by those classes give you more expressive power.